# Alert Controller Before Delete Cell Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, alert

I would like to know how to show a delete confirmation before a cell removal, (An alert). The cells are characters with info, so it would be bad if a user delete (swipe) one by mistake.

This is the snippet that allow me to delete my row. Im using Xcode 10 / Swift

```
// Delete Rows
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)

        self.namesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.imagesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    })
    modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .purple

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])

}
```

Comment: Simply add a `UIAlertController` inside the action block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the code to display a `UIAlertController` out into a separate method you can call when the user presses delete. Here's the code below, ensuring that all presentation logic contained within closures gets dispatched to the main thread.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.showDeleteWarning(for: indexPath)
        }

        success(true)
    })

    modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .purple

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}

func showDeleteWarning(for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Create the alert controller and actions
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Warning Title", message: "Warning Message", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.namesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.imagesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    //Add the actions to the alert controller
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(deleteAction)

    //Present the alert controller
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: No need for **DispatchQueue.main.async**

Comment: Hey @Sh_Khan, after thinking about that more and doing some searching I am seeing people mention that, because these are user-initiated actions, they believe they will always be invoked on the main thread. Do you have any documented proof? I can see what you're saying, and I can see it making sense, it would just be better if Apple has some explicit docs making this a concrete guarantee.

Comment: @KyleH The UIKit API always calls its code on the main queue when responding to UI events. It's a simple fact.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AbelC no problem! @rmaddy there have been issues filed before with presentation logic inside Apple's delegate methods that are tied to user initiated actions. While this radar is old (https://openradar.appspot.com/19563577) I can still produce the same delay today, and so can other's with more recent SO posts/Github issues, etc. So you could probably remove the calls back to the main thread in my code, I would just ensure that you're not running into similar delays as you would in the `didSelectRowAtIndex` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)

         let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Are you sure you want to delete the item ? ", preferredStyle: .alert)
         let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
             self.namesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
             self.imagesArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)     
             self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        })
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style:.cancel, handler: { (alert) in
             print("Cancel")
        })
        alertView.addAction(okAction)
        alertView.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    })
    modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .purple 
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])

}
```